# How to select elements without a class by not using :not()?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, capybara

when I did some automation tests using Capybara and Selenium Webdriver, I got the problem with selecting elements without a class by using :not attribute. 
This is our sample 'div' of elements:

```
<div class="intro__card__container">
    <div class="ic--card off" id="pic1"><img alt="Image1" src="/images/landing/intro/image1.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
    <div class="ic--card off" id="pic2"><img alt="Image2" src="/images/landing/intro/image2.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
    <div class="ic--card off" id="pic3"><img alt="Image3" src="/images/landing/intro/image3.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
    <div class="ic--card" id="pic4"><img alt="Image4" src="/images/landing/intro/image4.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
    <div class="ic--card off" id="pic5"><img alt="Image5" src="/images/landing/intro/image5.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
    <div class="ic--card off" id="pic6"><img alt="Image6" src="/images/landing/intro/image6.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
    <div class="ic--card" id="pic7"><img alt="Image7" src="/images/landing/intro/image7.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
    <div class="ic--card off" id="pic8"><img alt="Image8" src="/images/landing/intro/image8.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
    <div class="ic--card off" id="pic9"><img alt="Image9" src="/images/landing/intro/image9.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
    <div class="ic--card off" id="pic10"><img alt="Image10" src="/images/landing/intro/image10.jpg" class="ic--image"></div>
</div>
```

I am using this selector ".ic--card:not('.off')" to select elements without 'off' class. It works for jQuery but doesn't valid in Selenium test. So how can I select elements without '.off' class?

Comment: what code are you using with that selector ??  Any valid css should work since it's passed directly to the browser.  Are you sure the elements are visible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok - looking at this again ".ic--card:not('.off')"   the 's around .off are not a valid css selector since .off would not be quoted as a class selector.  Using

```
find(".ic--card:not(.off)")
```

should work fine

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

1. css:

   `find("div[class='ic--card']")`
2. xpath:

   `find("//div[contains(@class,'ic--card') and not(contains(@class,'off'))]")`